# Python not recognizing multilevel index

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe that currently looks like this:

```
country series year value 
usa     a      2010 21
usa     b      2015 22
usa     a      2017 23
usa     b      2010 22
usa     b      2017 23

aus     a      2010 21
aus     b      2015 22
aus     a      2017 23
aus     b      2010 22
aus     b      2017 23
```

When I run this code, it reduces the duplicity of the countries but not the series like I expect it to.

```
pop2.set_index(['Country','Series'])
```

I want:

```
country series year value 
usa     a      2010 21
               2017 23
        b      2010 22
               2015 22
               2017 23
aus     a      2010 21                  
               2017 23
        b      2010 22
               2015 22
               2017 23
```

Instead, it is returning:

```
country series year value 
usa     a      2010 21
        b      2015 22
        a      2017 23
        b      2010 22
        b      2017 23
aus     a      2010 21
        b      2015 22
        a      2017 23
        b      2010 22
        b      2017 23
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

Comment: What about a groupby instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an index label for each row to display in a dataframe.  Therefore, you need is a another level of index then you can show index "grouping" as you wish.

Let's try this:

```
df.set_index(['country','series',np.arange(df.shape[0])]).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                  year  value
country series               
aus     a      5  2010     21
               7  2017     23
        b      6  2015     22
               8  2010     22
               9  2017     23
usa     a      0  2010     21
               2  2017     23
        b      1  2015     22
               3  2010     22
               4  2017     23
```